# Slow loading UIWebView from string

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am trying to load a `UIWebView` from a string as follows:

```
    NSString* plainContent = @"...";
    NSString* htmlContentString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   @"<html>"
                                   "<style type=\"text/css\">"
                                   "body { background-color:transparent; font-family:Arial-BoldMT; font-size:18;}"
                                   "</style>"
                                   "<body>"
                                   "<p>%@</p>"
                                   "</body></html>", plainContent] retain];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlContentString baseURL:nil];
```

Where plain content has some simple HTML with about 5 links and 400 characters. I'm trying to run this on my iPhone5, and the first time it loads it always take a few seconds. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens because of `CSS` used in rendering web page. It is default behavior when  loading page locally. We can also consider that in first load, `UIWebview` doesn't have cache to this and create cache for that page.

To make it little fast try loading page from a file e.g.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filePath" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"."]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

`CSS` like `body { background-color:transparent; font-family:Arial-BoldMT; font-size:18;}` also increase the time of loading a page.

Answer (score 6):

I recently struggled with UIWebView performance. It seemed to take a very long time to process the local HTML I was providing (1 or 2 seconds on iPad Air 2 simulator) even if it was ridiculously small.

After a lot of googling around, I found that the culprit was the **phone numbers detection** on webview. Once I unchecked it on the storyboard, the latency was gone.

Hope it helps someone facing the same issue :)

Comment: You are correct Bro... Thanks that worked for me... :-)

Comment: What is the best web\location to disable phone numbers detection from code?
        self.webview.dataDetectorTypes = []

Answer (score 0):

For other who experienced this problems, sometimes we created HTML file by copy-paste-ing from existing websites and we're forget to check the links on header.

In my case, I forgot to remove unused link rel in my html string header:

```
NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><title>%@</title><link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://192.168.3.183/assets/css/question.css?1383042738\" /></head><body><h1 style=\"font-size: 2em; margin-bottom: 0; color: #3357b8; font-weight: bold\">%@</h1><div style=\"color: #555\">%@</div><br><p style=\"line-height: 1.7em\">%@</p><a href=\"%@\"><b>Open in browser</b></a><br></body></html>", title, title, dateString, content, detail];
```

The local URL pointed by above link rel make loading time even worst.

```
<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://192.168.3.183/assets/css/question.css?1383042738\" />
```

Just don't forget to re-check your header or other link in your HTML string and remove it if it is not used.

Answer (score -1):

In case of `WKWebView`, disabling WKWebView's data detectors worked for me. Swift version:

```
let webViewCofig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webViewCofig.dataDetectorTypes = []
webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: webViewCofig)
```

To enable specific data detector, pass the specific type as .address,.link etc while setting dataDetectorTypes:

```
config.dataDetectorTypes = [.address]
```